# Running a long running process via Python Popen

Tags: python, unix, development-environment, multiprocessing

So, I thought it would be cool if i could get my dev env up and running in a single fell swoop with some python magic. Various DBs, webserver etc.

However, every variation on the below that i have tried on the following seems to fail with 'file not found'.

```
p2 = Popen(["exec", "/path/to/redis/server"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE) 
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Running the command directly from the shell (i.e. `exec /path/to/redis/server`) works just fine. Strangely enough, a simple command line `uptime` seems to work fine.

Any clues as to what is going on? Also, whilst we are on the topic, is `multiprocessing` the thing to use when i want to run many of these external processes in parallel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` is a builtin command in bash, not an executable. The file not found error probably comes from exec not being found in the `$PATH`.

I would try ommitting "exec" in the `Popen` call.